# Why getting thid error: g++ is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file?

Tags: c++, gcc, command-line, environment-variables, version

I have installed g++ compiler for Windows 10 (64 bit) using this guide provided in official VS Code docs:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

I have also added the Path in the Environment variables as:
[image]

Still I'm getting this error:

```
The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ g++ --version
+ ~~~
```

while checking the version of g++ on Powershell using:

```
g++ --version
gcc --version
gmd --version
```

Comment: Have you restarted Visual Studio Code and Windows PowerShell?

Comment: @273K Ya I did that multiple times.

Comment: You don't seem to install GCC with pacman. You seemed to stop on installing only msys2 package manger.

Comment: @273k how do I get pacman then?

Comment: Just follow the tutorial https://www.msys2.org/ that is referenced on the page you linked

Comment: Side note: take advantage of the package manager. MSYS2 has an fantastic support library. You'll probably want to install [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) at the very least because it's the C++ Swiss Army Chainsaw. It has a tool to simplify almost everything. But if you install it yourself it'll take quite a while to set up correctly.